# MongoDb insert or add in embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is my **final** document structure.  I am on ***mongo 3.0***.

```
   {
     _id: "1",
     stockA: [ { size: "S", qty: 25 }, { size: "M", qty: 50 } ],
     stockB: [ { size: "S", qty: 27 }, { size: "M", qty: 58 } ]
   }
```

I am randomly adding elements inside `stockA` or `stockB` collections. 
I would like come up with a query which would satisfy following rules:

1. If `item` is not exist - create whole document and insert item in `stock A or B` collection.
2. If `item` is exist but `stock A or B` collection is missing create `stock` collection and add `element` inside collection.
3. if `item` is exist and `stock` collection is exist just append `element` inside collection.

Question: Is it possible to achieve all that in one query? My main requirement that current insert has to be extremely fast and scalable.

If **yes**, could you please help me to come up with required query.

If **no**, could you please guide me how do I achieve requirements in fastest and cleanest way.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: And what about  `details` and `category` fields?

Comment: @Michael, ignore them for now. Lets do it just for collections. Basically assume I have only `_id` and set of collections inside document.

Comment: You are keeping using the word "collection", but what you actually seem to mean is "array". Could that be true? Please try to use the correct terminology, or you confuse both others and yourself. The entity hierarchy in MongoDB is: one database has many collections, one collection has many documents, one document can have many fields, arrays and subdocuments, an array or subdocument can contain more fields, arrays and subdocuments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator you are looking for is [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) or  [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) in combination with [`upsert:true`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/).

Both operators can take multiple key/value pairs. It will then operate separately on each key. Both will create the array when it doesn't exist yet, and in either case will add the value.

The difference is that $addToSet will first check if an identical element already exists in the array. When performance is an issue, keep in mind that MongoDB must perform a linear search to do this. So for very large arrays, $addToSet can become quite slow.

The `upsert:true` option to the update function will result in the document being created when it isn't found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**`update`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) method with the `upsert` option  which will create a new document when no document matches the query criteria.

```js
db.collection.update({ "_id": 1 },
    {
        "$push" : {
            "stockB" : {
                           "size" : "M",
                           "qty" : 51
            },
           "stockA" : {
                           "size" : "M",
                           "qty" : 21
            }
        }
    }, 
    { "upsert": true }
)
```

Comment: Why `findAndModify` instead of just `update`? The OP doesn't indicate that they need the document after upserting it.

Comment: Thanks, both answers are amazing.