# MongoDB Data Model Optimization

Tags: performance, mongodb, optimization, data-modeling

**About**

I have raw data which is processed by aggregation framework and later results saved in another collection. Let's assume aggregation results in something like this:

```
cursor = {
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : {
            "x" : 1,
            "version" : [
                "2_0"
            ],
            "date" : {
                "year" : 2015,
                "month" : 3,
                "day" : 26
            }
        },
        "x" : 1,
        "count" : 2
    }
],
"ok" : 1
};
```

*Note that in most cases cursor length are more than about 2k elements.*

So, now i'm looping thought cursor ( *cursor.forEach* ) and performing following steps:

```
// Try to increment values:
var inc = db.runCommand({
    findAndModify: my_coll,
    query  : {
        "_id.x" : "1",
        "value.2_0" : {
            "$elemMatch" : {
                "date" : ISODate("2015-12-18T00:00:00Z")
            }
        }
    },
    update : { $inc:   {
        "value.2_0.$.x" : 1
    } }
});

// If there's no effected row via inc operation, - sub-element doesn't exists at all
// so let's push it
if (inc.value == null) {
    date[date.key] = date.value;
    var up = db.getCollection(my_coll).update(
        {
            "_id.x"    : 1
        },
        {
            $push : {}
        },
        { writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 5000 } }
    );

// No document found for inserting sub element, let's create it
if (up.nMatched == 0) {
    db.getCollection(my_coll).insert({
        "_id" : {
            "x"    : 1
        },
        "value" : {}
    });
}}
```

Resulting data-structure:

```
data = {
"_id" : {
"x" : 1,
"y" : 1
},
"value" : {
"2_0" : [
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2014-12-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "x" : 1
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2014-12-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "x" : 2
    }
]
}
};
```

In short i have to apply these actions to process my data:

- Try to increment values.
- If there's no effected data by increment operation push data to array.
- If there's no effected data by push operation create new document.

**Problem:**

In some cases aggregation result returns more than 2k results i have to apply mentioned steps who causes performance bottleneck. While i'm processing already aggregated data, - new data accumulates for aggregation and later i cannot apply even aggregation to this new raw data because it exceeds 64MB size limit due firsts slowness.

**Question:**

How i can with this data-structure improve performance when increasing *x* ( see data-stucture ) values or adding-sub elements?

Also i cannot apply mongodb *bulk operations* due nested structure using positional parameter.

Maybe chosen data-model is not correct? Or maybe i'm doing not correctly aggregation task at all?
How i can improve aggregated data insertions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDb insert or add in embedded document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231964/mongodb-insert-or-add-in-embedded-document)

Comment: @Philipp, in my case, i need to increment value if it does exists and if doesn't not then create new one. In your provided link, the aim is always to append new element.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? It looks like pre-2.6, before aggregation pipelines returned cursors, and that's why you have 16MB limits on aggregation results. Are you processing the results from the aggregation in parallel? How quickly is data coming in? If you are retrieving the document with findAndModify, why not just recall it, put it in final form, and re-save it, instead of trying multiple updates?

Comment: @wdberkeley, i'm using 2.6.3 MongoDB version. What do you mean "processing the aggregation in parallel"? I'm using cron to initialize aggregation and processing which executes .js file via mongo shell. Can you paste a code sample, please about findAndModify?